# Cleanup of JSP files, script holder

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

In our project we have close to 200 jsp files. Each of these files have `<script>some code</script>`. There is a lot of duplication of code here. Are there any design patterns out there that I can use ?

I have currently thought about doing the following

1. `commonscripts.jsp` will be the parent scripts holder file
2. `onloadadddriverscriptholder.jsp` will include `commonscripts.jsp` and some other specific scripts that are not used anywhere else.
3. `onloadmodifydriversscriptholder.jsp` will include `commonscripts.jsp` and `onloadadddriversscriptholder.jsp` and other specific scripts that are not used anywhere else.

Is there a better way to do this ?

I am not a jsp developer, so pardon my terminology, but please focus on the problem at hand. I need to refactor code for neatness and reusability.

Comment: The scripts that you are referring to is javascript?

Comment: Yes, thanks, javascript

Comment: Add some framework like Apache Tiles to create a base template and use it. The base template will include all the scripts that are common. Also separate the JS into separate files and include in the JSP.